How to select a range of 9 rows starting at a3:g3 to a10:g10, then copy/paste to another column?
Sub Macro1Loop()
'
'
' Macro1Loop()

Range("A2:G10").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("J2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Started with the range selection and copy/paste works fine.
How can I add a loop function, so it goes to the next range, for example, continuing to range A3:G11, and copy/paste this next range of 9 rows to the next empty row in column J.
Then continue down to range A4:G12 and so forth, until an empty row is reached starting in column A.

Do you want to copy only the data or also the formatting?

When you say an empty row is reached starting in column A.  Do you mean just column A will be empty, or all columns from A:G will be empty? Will there be data below that blank row or looking for the last row of data on the sheet? I'm asking as it's easier to check just the single column rather than all of them.

Your post title says 9 rows starting at a3:g3 to a10:g10 ? that is 8 rows

Here is my code.
Sub Macro1Loop()
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim destinationRow As Long
    
    startRow = 2
    rowCount = 9

    Do
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        If IsEmpty(Cells(startRow, 1)) Then Exit Do
        
        destinationRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        Range(Cells(startRow, 1), Cells(startRow + rowCount - 1, 7)).Copy
        
        Range("J" & destinationRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        startRow = startRow + 1
        
    Loop
    
End Sub


Sub CopyBlock()

    Const ROW_START = 2
    Const ROW_COUNT = 9
    Const COL_COUNT = 7
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngDest As Range, rngSrc As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngSrc = ws.Cells(ROW_START, "A").Resize(ROW_COUNT, COL_COUNT)
    Set rngDest = ws.Range("J2")
    
    Do While WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rngSrc.Rows(ROW_COUNT)) < COL_COUNT

        rngSrc.Copy rngDest
        
        Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Offset(1)
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(ROW_COUNT)
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    
    MsgBox n & " blocks copied", vbInformation

End Sub


Much appreciated, thank you smooch as this works perfectly.

Copy/Append

Sub Macro1Loop()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "A2:G5"
    Const SRC_ROW_OFFSET As Long = 1
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "J2"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the source copy range.
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = ws.Range(SRC_RANGE_ADDRESS)
    Dim sRowsCount As Long: sRowsCount = scrg.Rows.Count
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = scrg.Columns.Count
     
    ' Calculate the number of copies.
    Dim CopiesCount As Long
    With scrg
        Dim slcell As Range
        With .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
            Set slcell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        End With
        If Not slcell Is Nothing Then
            CopiesCount = slcell.Row - .Row - sRowsCount + 2
            If CopiesCount < 1 Then CopiesCount = 1
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell.
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = ws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Clear existing data in the destination columns.
    dcell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - dcell.Row + 1, ColumnsCount).Clear
    
    ' Copy.
    Dim CopiesOffset As Long
    For CopiesOffset = 0 To CopiesCount - 1
        scrg.Offset(CopiesOffset * SRC_ROW_OFFSET).Copy _
            Destination:=dcell.Offset(CopiesOffset * sRowsCount)
    Next CopiesOffset
        
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox CopiesCount & " range" & IIf(CopiesCount = 1, "", "s") _
        & " copied.", IIf(CopiesCount = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation)
        
End Sub

